# Disable WooCommerce order email notification for orders with custom status

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I have searched the web and checked the [WooCommerce docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/unhookremove-woocommerce-emails/) for a solution to disable the "confirmation email" that is sent to the customer when they place an order in WooCoomerce.

I also want to disable the "new order" mail that goes to the admin.

**But only if the order has a custom status "mystatus",** which some orders are getting based on what the customers are ordering.

Tried adding it like this, but it did not work:

`remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_mystatus_notification', array($email_class->emails['WC_Email_New_Order'], 'trigger' ) );?>`

Any advice?

---

This is how I change the order status for specific orders:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou','woocommerce_thankyou_change_order_status', 10, 1 );
function woocommerce_thankyou_change_order_status( $order_id ){
if( ! $order_id ) return;

$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$user_id = $order->get_user_id();

if( ($order->get_status() == 'processing'  || $order->get_status() == 'pending' || $order->get_status() == 'on-hold' ) && dokan_is_user_seller( $user_id ) && is_user_logged_in()) {
    $order->update_status( 'mystatus' );
  }
}
```

Comment: The default WooCommerce emails can be turned on/off or configured in WooCommerce >> Settings >> Emails. After this you can find out on SO how to sent WooCommerce emails manually. This would be the best approach I think.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to keep the default emails as they are, its only if the order has my custom order status I want do disable it (and cant see any options in the Settings -> Emails)

Comment: But this way is much simpler than the other way... Just disable the email you want to send only when your order has a specific status and send the mail programmatically. This is really no big deal...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No real need to make any changes to WooCommerce settings.

**No email-notifications will be sent for a custom order status**, unless you effectively provide this.

However, the default email-notifications are sent, because the `woocommerce_thankyou` hook is **executed after the email-notifications have been sent.**

So use the `woocommerce_checkout_order_created` hook (that is executed, before the e-mail notifications are sent) opposite `woocommerce_thankyou` to change the order status, and no emails will be sent anyway.

```php
function action_woocommerce_checkout_order_created( $order ) {
    // Get user ID
    $user_id = $order->get_user_id();
    
    // Compare
    if ( ( $order->get_status() == 'processing'  || $order->get_status() == 'pending' || $order->get_status() == 'on-hold' ) && dokan_is_user_seller( $user_id ) && is_user_logged_in() ) {
        // Update status
        $order->update_status( 'mystatus' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_created', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_order_created', 10, 1 );
```

---

**Note: If you want to disable emails in any other case**, you can use the `woocommerce_email_recipient_{$email_id}` filter composite hook and with the right email ID set, you have the option to disable email notifications.

For instance:

```php
// Admin - new order email notification
// Customer - on hold
// Customer - processing
// Customer - pending
function filter_woocommerce_email_recipient( $recipient, $order, $email ) { 
    if ( ! $order || ! is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) return $recipient;
    
    // Has order status
    if ( $order->has_status( 'your-order-status' ) ) {
        $recipient = '';
    }

    return $recipient;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'filter_woocommerce_email_recipient', 10, 3 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_on_hold_order', 'filter_woocommerce_email_recipient', 10, 3 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_processing_order', 'filter_woocommerce_email_recipient', 10, 3 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_pending_order', 'filter_woocommerce_email_recipient', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Thank you for a very detailed answer. This makes very much sense (and also works, of course).

Answer (score 3):

Disable the mail under `WooCommerce >> Settings >> Emails` you want to only sent in case your order has a custom status.

Now just sent it in case your order has the correct status:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'woocommerce_thankyou_change_order_status', 10, 1 );
function woocommerce_thankyou_change_order_status( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! $order_id ) {
        return;
    }

    $order   = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $user_id = $order->get_user_id();

    if ( ( $order->get_status() == 'processing' || $order->get_status() == 'pending' || $order->get_status() == 'on-hold' ) && dokan_is_user_seller( $user_id ) && is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $order->update_status( 'mystatus' );

        $email_oc = new WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order();
        $email_oc->trigger($order_id);
    }
}
```

You can just sent every WooCommerce mail from PHP you want.

Comment: Ah, now I understood what you meant earlier. Seems like a good idea! I tried this, only replaced the part so the correct email is sent: `WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order`. But this gave error `Uncaught Error: Class 'WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order' not found in ...` Any advice?

Comment: Maybe you need to import the class. What does your IDE says? Normally you IDE says you if a class needs to be imported or not.